# How to add text after last pattern match using ed

Tags: linux, bash, ed

This is how I am adding text before *first* pattern,
I want to add after *last* pattern

```
FILE_NAME="folder/myfile.c++"
STR_TO_ADD="string that i want to add"
PATTERN="banana"
ed $FILE_NAME 2>NULL 1>NULL<<EOF
/^$PATTERN
-1
a
$STR_TO_ADD
.
wq
EOF
```

## file

```
banana
apple
banana
one
two
three
```

## Expected output

```
banana
apple
banana
string that i want to add
one
two
three
```

Comment: Many thanks, another small question.

The pattern search is finding the line only if it starts from the begining of the line, how can i inform that the begining is not known?

Answer (score 1):

Go to last line of file and search pattern in backward direction.

```
FILE_NAME="folder/myfile.c++"
STR_TO_ADD="string that i want to add"
PATTERN="banana"
ed $FILE_NAME 2>NULL 1>NULL<<EOF
$
?^$PATTERN
a
$STR_TO_ADD
.
wq
EOF
```

`$` last line of file.
`?^$PATTERN` search pattern in backward direction from current line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by user0 is close, but if the last match falls on the last line of the file, it will find the previous one. Instead, go to the **first** line and search backward:

```
1
?^$PATTERN
a
$STR_TO_ADD
.
```

I [just posted this on my `@ed1conf` account](https://twitter.com/ed1conf/status/1146746295476019201) a couple days ago so it's fresh in my mind.

Additionally, if you're trying to add *before* the text (the example you already have), it will fail if the first match is on the first line because the "`-1`" goes before the start of the file.  Instead, use the "`i`" command to insert the text rather than append it:

```
$
/^$PATTERN
i
$STR_TO_ADD
.
```

You might also need to ensure that "`$STR_TO_ADD`" doesn't contain any lines containing a single period or the variable-expansion will prematurely terminate the `i`nsertion (or `a`ppending).