# ed pattern - the first chars in line is unknown

Tags: linux, bash, ed

This is how I am adding text before first pattern reveal:

```
FILE_NAME="folder/myfile.c++"
STR_TO_ADD="string that i want to add"
PATTERN="banana"

ed $FILE_NAME 2>NULL 1>NULL<<EOF
/^$PATTERN
-1
a
$STR_TO_ADD
.
wq
EOF
```

but if the line is started with some characters before the "banana" so it is not working.
mostly white-speces but i whould like to hear answer for all characters.
thanks!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: When something is NOT working as you intend, it is never a good idea to throw away possible error and warning messages. Also your code `2>NULL 1>NULL` is creating a file named `NULL` in your current working directory, it is NOT discarding the errors and warnings, etc. Remove those 2 things and see if you get any error messages. When it is all working **then** you can add `>/dev/null 2>&1` . Good luck.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `ed` for this instead of `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Isn't it the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932739/how-to-add-text-after-last-pattern-mach-using-ed)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be doing what (I surmise) you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME="folder/myfile.c++"
STR_TO_ADD="string that i want to add"
PATTERN="banana"

ed $FILE_NAME <<EOF
/^$PATTERN
-1
a
$STR_TO_ADD
.
wq
EOF
```